# Error when restoring database to a new server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I receive the following error when I try to restore a database to SQL Server 2008 from SQL Server 2008 Express R2:

> *The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.2500. 
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running 10.00.4064. 
>   Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup 
>   that is compatible with this server.*

Is there anything that I can do to fix this or am I stuck using SQL Server Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot go "back" in SQL Server versions - if your database is on **2008 R2** (v10.50) - you cannot back it up and restore it onto a **2008** (v10.00) version.

There's no trick, no workaround, no hack - it just **cannot be done** - period.

So you either need to upgrade your target system to **2008 R2** as well (Express will do, as long as the size is below 10 GB), or you need to script out structure and data to `.sql` files to run those on your "old" 2008 system (possibly using third-party tools like Red-Gate SQL Compare / SQL Data Compare to create those scripts and possibly run them against the target server directly).

Comment: I've just tried the Export Data wizard and that seemed to work? Only problem was that my keys / identities weren't set?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff: if you only need to transport data - yes, that's definitely an option

Comment: Yeah, I only want to copy it all over, but as I said, my identites / computed columns, PK's, FK's etc.. are all lost?